# PowerShell подставляет "--" перед именем пакета npm

Tags: windows-10, npm, powershell

Ввожу команду на Win10:

```
$ npx --version
8.19.2
$ npx eslint --fix .
```

Вывод:

```
строка:1 знак:3
+ -- eslint --fix .
+   ~
Отсутствует выражение после унарного оператора "--".
строка:1 знак:4
+ -- eslint --fix .
+    ~~~~~~
Непредвиденная лексема "eslint" в выражении или операторе.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

В то же время под WSL-Ubuntu всё работает. Как разрешить эту проблему?

Comment: Запустите cmd.exe - Командная строка и всё получится. Правая кнопка мышки на значке виндовс (обычно слева внизу)

Comment: @Виктор Вы имеете в виду, что лучше отказаться от powershell?

Comment: ну Вам же пакет надо починить - так быстрее, чем разбираться что не так. Как время будет, так и разберётесь

Comment: @Виктор Там то же самое.

Comment: У меня `C:\Projects\QT\taskTkInter>npx eslint --fix                                                         Need to install the following packages:
  eslint@8.28.0
Ok to proceed? (y)`  Это из cmd.exe

Comment: @Виктор Да, у меня тоже так. Он так ведёт себя в директории, где нет npm-проекта с локальным `eslint`. Сам по себе `npx` среда видит.

Comment: Обновите npm install npm@latest -g   Я попробовал npm update eslint - у меня так восстановило

Comment: @Виктор Точно, как раз удалил его на днях. Заработало. Спасибо!